# Setting the value of a TextField without onChange but with Enter

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/textfield in an accounting-type of software. I'd like the TextField to change the state value only after pressing Enter so that intermediate result doesn't change the state.

Meaning if I had a value 123.45, and I'm deleting 4 characters to 12 then adding 4 resulting in 124.56, I don't want the state to change to 12 making all other numbers jump.

Is there onEnter? or should I capture each character and check if it's enter?

ps. what about submitting on the deactivation of the TextField from the edit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use onKeyPress, then grab the current value via a ref.

You can also track the input value as it changes via state, then sync state on enter. Either way.

https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/Ydxjdz?editors=1011

```js
class TextFieldBasicExample extends React.Component<any, any> {
  
  field = React.createRef();
  
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className="docs-TextFieldExample">
        <TextField componentRef={this.field} label="Standard" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  handleKeyPress = (event, value) => {
    if(event.key == 'Enter'){
      console.log(this.field.current.value)
    }
  }
}
```